# MySQL SELECT Coding

Tags: mysql

I am creating code for the following question and for one reason or another the code is not working.  Would someone mind taking a look at it and tell me why it is not working or give me a suggestion?

Create a query (SELECT statement) to display all the records in the table tblEmployee that have related records in the table tblEmployeeTraining

My Code =

```
SELECT tblEmployee , tblEmployeeTraining FROM
homework WHERE tblEmployee = tblEmployeeTraining;
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a `inner join`

```
SELECT e.*
FROM tblEmployee e
INNER JOIN tblEmployeeTraining t on t.employee_id = e.id
```

You have to name the columns you want to select. if you want to select all columns of a specifc table you can do `select tablename.* from ...`

Comment: +1; I missed the `JOIN` initially. May want to add the column list goes after `SELECT`.